# connecting ibm cloud to aws cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, ibm-cloud

let say I wanted to connect my IBM cloud to an aws vpc so that you could talk to machines on both ends via private IPs. I know you'd have to deal with routing and what not, but how would one do that? Would you have to use a virtual private gateway or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **software VPN appliance** to join the two networks.

This will involve running **VPN software**, such as [Openswan](https://www.openswan.org/), in publicly-accessible subnets of both networks.

Alternatively, you could use an Amazon VPC virtual gateway on one end and a software appliance on the other end.

See the *Software VPN* section of this whitepaper for some examples: [Amazon VPC Connectivity Options](https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/amazon-vpc-connectivity-options/)